# SwfUpload: prevent_swf_caching in other browsers than IE?

Tags: javascript, swfupload

I'm using SwfUpload and in a page speed optimization project I noticed that in the default setting swfupload prevents loading of the swfupload.swf by appending a random querystring.

This is beacause of an IE bug when the swf is fetched from cache.

But I really want to cache this file. :(

Is this an acceptable workarbound for at least not caching other browsers than IE:

```
prevent_swf_caching:!!$.browser.msie,
```

Answer (score -1):

Revelvant code is:

```
if (!!this.settings.prevent_swf_caching) {
            this.settings.flash_url = this.settings.flash_url + (this.settings.flash_url.indexOf("?") < 0 ? "?" : "&") + "preventswfcaching=" + new Date().getTime();
 }

/*snip*/
this.ensureDefault("prevent_swf_caching", true);
```

So, when you initialize it, just pass the user setting of

```
{"prevent_swf_caching": !$.browser.msie }
```

Comment: Yes, so much I've figured out myself. The question is more if it's okay to prevent caching only for IE.